# spring-boot 1.3-M5 oauth2 SSO does not work with spring-session?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-session

Basically I cannot get spring-boot oauth2 integration to work with spring-session.

I created an issue in spring-boot's issue tracker:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4360

I made a repo to demonstrate this problem

https://github.com/sloppycoder/spring-session-oauth-problem

there're 2 modules:

- auth-server is the oauth2 authorization server. to run it, just `mvn`. the server will be at http://localhost:19999/uaa
- web-app is the web application that uses the auth-server for single sign-on. `mvn` will start the app on http://localhost:8080

My sso logout logic works like this:

1. click on "Logout" button will do a POST to http://localhost:19999/uaa/logout, with passing the URL to redirect to, http://localhost:8080/ssologout, after successful logout.
2. auth-server logout and redirect to http://localhost:8080/ssologout
3. http://localhost:8080/ssologout then POST to http://localhost:8080/logout
4. (default spring-security behavior) after logout, redirect to http://localhost:8080/login?logout
5. http://localhost:8080/login?logout redirect to http://localhost:19999/uaa/login and prompt user to login again.

However after I bring in the spring-session, step #5 is not happening. the browser goes directly to web-app /dashboard.

make sure you start your local redis daemon before running the sos-spring-session branch.

I created 2 branches to show the different behavior:

1. sso-only. spring-boot integrates with auth-server and things work fine.
2. sso-spring-sesson. logout does not work.

[github compare](https://github.com/sloppycoder/spring-session-oauth-problem/compare/sso-only...sso-spring-session) shows the difference.

I'll appreciate any advise and suggestions on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem on spring-boot 1.3.0.RC1, spring-session and redis.

[spring-boot 1.3.0.RC1 : ClassCastException in getting oauth2 user info from session persisted in Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229311/spring-boot-1-3-0-rc1-classcastexception-in-getting-oauth2-user-info-from-sess)

It may work if you change filter order as

'requestContextFilter' < 'OAuth2ClientContextFilter' < 'springSessionRepositoryFilter'

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(RequestContextFilter.class)
public RequestContextFilter requestContextFilter() {

  return new RequestContextFilter();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean requestContextFilterChainRegistration(
  @Qualifier("requestContextFilter") Filter securityFilter) {

  FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(securityFilter);
  registration.setName("requestContextFilter");

  // note : must previous order of oAuth2ClientContextFilter
  registration.setOrder(SessionRepositoryFilter.DEFAULT_ORDER + 1);

  return registration;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration(
  SessionRepositoryFilter sessionRepositoryFilter) {

  FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(sessionRepositoryFilter);
  registration.setName("springSessionRepositoryFilter");

  // note : must following order of oAuth2ClientContextFilter
  registration.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1);

  return registration;
}
```

also you may need to remove dependency `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools`

related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3805

---

**postscript: for spring-boot 1.3.3.RELEASE**

spring-session, redis, spring-security-oauth2 works below filter order.

```
# logs on bootRun task
Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'OAuth2ClientContextFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
```

---

current required setting is below.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(RequestContextFilter.class)
public RequestContextFilter requestContextFilter() {
  return new RequestContextFilter();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean requestContextFilterChainRegistration(
  @Qualifier("requestContextFilter") Filter securityFilter) {

  FilterRegistrationBean registration = 
    new FilterRegistrationBean(securityFilter);

  registration.setName("requestContextFilter");

  // note : must to be following order of springSessionRepositoryFilter
  registration.setOrder(SessionRepositoryFilter.DEFAULT_ORDER + 1);

  return registration;
}
```

Comment: Yep, it worked. Thanks very much. the commit is here for all readers. https://github.com/sloppycoder/spring-session-oauth-problem/commit/4bcf5df70c718845f39ac5765cd1425b36edd525

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues with that code, but the one that stops it working with Spring Session is that the two apps are sharing a cookie. The context-path is "/" for the "main" webapp, so the auth server tries to use the same cookie when it is running on the same host. It doesn't matter when you use a local session, but when you use a distributed session you mess up the state when the 2 apps try to share the same session. You can fix it by using a `server.context-path` in the webapp (e.g. `/app`) and making corresponding changes to your HTML etc. to make sure that the browser follows paths back to there.